# how to get the week dates within given year and month PHP

Tags: php

I do have this variables

```
$year = 2014;
$month = 02;
$cntWeek = 2;
```

how do I get the dates of the second week of february 2014

I must get

```
2014-02-02
2014-02-03
2014-02-04
2014-02-05
2014-02-06
2014-02-07
2014-02-08
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: http://www.silverphp.com/simple-functions-to-get-all-dates-between-two-dates-using-php-code.html

Comment: how about using my only 3 variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick function I threw together that appears to work:

```
<?php


function get_nth_week_of_month($year, $month, $cntWeek) {

    $begin = new DateTime( "$year-$month-01" );
    $end = clone($begin);
    $end->modify("+1 month");

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    $dates = array();
    $cur_week = 1;
    foreach($daterange as $date) {
        if ($date->format("N") == 7 && $date->format('d') != 1) {
            $cur_week++;
        }
        if ($cur_week == $cntWeek) {
            $dates[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
        }
    }

    return $dates;
}

print_r(get_nth_week_of_month(2014, 2, 2));
```

The output of the above is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-02-02
    [1] => 2014-02-03
    [2] => 2014-02-04
    [3] => 2014-02-05
    [4] => 2014-02-06
    [5] => 2014-02-07
    [6] => 2014-02-08
)
```

Comment: Wait, I found a bug in it if the first day of the month is Sunday (e.g. Nov 2015). I updated the code.

Comment: also this,   $end = $end->modify( '-1 day' ); this doesnt show feb 28, 2014, what exactly does it do :D

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize that DatePeriod doesn't use the last date, which is why I subtracted 1 day. Weird that the manual doesn't even mention that.

Comment: @StingHands your edit was rejected. Generally they get rejected if they alter too much of the logic in the answer. I updated the answer with the fix for December.

Comment: I just edited this a bit to be a bit cleaner. I was tired when I first wrote it and didn't think about just adding 1 month to the begin date.